# How can I map Countries on a ThreeJS Sphere?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js, coordinates

I am currently working on a project including a 3D Earth.
I created a 3D Sphere using ThreeJS and everything works fine

Now here's the thing:

I want the countries to be interactive or rather customisable. I want some countries to have a different color than others and so on.

I figured that a possible way to achieve this is to Draw Each Country as a Polygon on a 2D Canvas, then map the canvas onto the sphere.

Problem: I got the Geo Data from here: https://geojson-maps.ash.ms. This json Contains all the countries Border Coordinates as Lats and Longs like `let germany = [[-51.32, 24.53], [-10.43, 53.98], ...]`. How do I draw a polygon on the canvas at the according location using these Coordinates?

I have found a video where someone did exactly what I want to do. He implemented it in Unity. Maybe this helps to understand what I want to achieve: https://youtu.be/sLqXFF8mlEU?t=636. (Start at 10:37)

I am relatively new to Programming and JS. I know there are similar questions on the web but I really do not understand the answers or they just don't fit my problem. My Head is steaming and I tried everything for the last 5 hours.

Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution that fits my problem:

```
function getPXfromLatLng(lat, lon) {
        let posX = ((lat + 180.0) * (canvasW / 360.0));
        let posY = (((lon * -1.0) + 90.0) * (canvasH / 180.0));
        return { x: posX, y: posY };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick thought: You could normalize the long values to the width of your canvas, and the lat values to the height of your canvas.

```js
const canvasW = 1024;
const canvasH = 512;

function getPXfromLatLng(lat, lon) {
    // Convert longitude to [0,1] range, then multiply by canvas width
    let posX = (lon + 180) / 360 * canvasW;
    

    // Convert lat to [0,1] range, then multiply by canvas height
    let posY = (lat + 90) / 180 * canvasH;

    return { x: posX, y: posY };
}
```

... although this wouldn't account for the cosine distortion you see in equirectangular projections as you approach the poles. There's a formula in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) that could probably help you achieve this distortion.